# unable to set common minimum duration for video recording with all android manufacture

Tags: android

I am working with an application where created video should be uploaded on respective server.
Before uploading it video duration time is setting dynamically with the response coming from server. what i am facing the issue with it, multiple android devices with different manufacture understand the provided value differently.

Please suggest what should i do?

Comment: I am using following answere:-

intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit", 60); 

but the duration time is not perfect in all android devices.

Comment: Because of Camera implementations are different with all OEMs and Models, so you may find different behaviour